# How to generate random string in dart?

Tags: dart

I want to create a function that generates a random string in dart. 
It should include alphabets and numbers all mixed together. How can I do that?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Or if you don't want to use a package you can make a simple implementation like:

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  print(getRandomString(5));  // 5GKjb
  print(getRandomString(10)); // LZrJOTBNGA
  print(getRandomString(15)); // PqokAO1BQBHyJVK
}

const _chars = 'AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz1234567890';
Random _rnd = Random();

String getRandomString(int length) => String.fromCharCodes(Iterable.generate(
    length, (_) => _chars.codeUnitAt(_rnd.nextInt(_chars.length))));
```

I should add that you should not use this code to generate passwords or other kind of secrets. If you do that, please at least use `Random.secure()` to create the random generator.

Answer (score 41):

**Option A with charCodes:**

```
import 'dart:math';

String generateRandomString(int len) {
  var r = Random();
  return String.fromCharCodes(List.generate(len, (index) => r.nextInt(33) + 89));
}
```

Generates random string using visible characters including special ones.

**Option B with a predefined string:**

```
import 'dart:math';

String generateRandomString(int len) {
  var r = Random();
  const _chars = 'AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz1234567890';
  return List.generate(len, (index) => _chars[r.nextInt(_chars.length)]).join();
}
```

Comment: Be aware that generating the `Random` object for each `String` is not really the best way. The reason for this is `Random()` will get a new generator based on a new seed generated internally which only has 32 bit of random. This makes it (if you generates a lot of random Strings) likely you get the same seed and therefore will generate the exact same `String`. This is the reason why I did put the `Random` object outside of my method so we don't create a new seeded random generator constantly. This is not a problem since the random generator is very good without the risks of looping.

Comment: I should add that `Random.secure()` does not have the same problem since every random number from this generator comes from the OS. But you could still prevent an object to be created by caching a single instance.

Comment: Thank you :) @julemand101

Answer (score 24):

Found this in a [blog article](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Dart/Generating-a-Crypto-Random-String-in-Dart) about crypto strings:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:convert';

String getRandString(int len) {
  var random = Random.secure();
  var values = List<int>.generate(len, (i) =>  random.nextInt(255));
  return base64UrlEncode(values);
}
```

The string always ends with `==`. I would also assume that it's not the fastest solution.
But you don't need third party packages and don't have to declare obscure constants.

Answer (score 10):

```
import 'dart:math';
    
    String generateRandomString(int len) {
    var r = Random();
    String randomString =String.fromCharCodes(List.generate(len, (index)=> r.nextInt(33) + 89));
      return randomString;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you care about the uniqueness and security of your random string, you can use [UUID package](https://pub.dev/packages/uuid) easily

```
var uuid = Uuid();
// Generate a v1 (time-based) id
uuid.v1(); // -> '6c84fb90-12c4-11e1-840d-7b25c5ee775a'
// Generate a v4 (random) id
uuid.v4(); // -> '110ec58a-a0f2-4ac4-8393-c866d813b8d1'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'dart:math';

String generateRandomPassword(int length) {
  const String charset = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#\$%^&*()_+';

  Random random = Random();
  String password = '';

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    int randomIndex = random.nextInt(charset.length);
    password += charset[randomIndex];
  }

  return password;
}

void main() {
  int passwordLength = 12; // Change this to your desired password length
  String password = generateRandomPassword(passwordLength);
  print('Random Password: $password');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:math';
String randomPassword(int length){
    String characters =
      'AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz1234567890';
  Random rndInt = Random();
  String password = '';
  for (int i = 0; i <lenght; i++){
    password +=characters[rndInt.nextInt(characters.length)];
  }
  return ('Your new password is $password');
```

}

Comment: its a little long but its actually simple and not need using chr.

Comment: There are multiple things that are less optimal. First, using `Random()` for password generation are very bad since the amount of unique passwords that can be generated here is limited to 32 bit since that is the value used as "seed" for the random generator. I would here recommend using at least `Random.secure()` if you need this for password generation since it will ask your operating system for random data each time being asked and is therefore to be considered a lot better random source.

Comment: Second, is that appending characters to string using `+=` is less optimal since Dart will here create a new String for each loop iteration. I recommend looking into `StringBuffer` which is designed for creating a String in multiple steps: https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.1.2/dart-core/StringBuffer-class.html

Comment: I would also not call the parameter for `_length` since it does not make much sense in this context. Just call it `length`. Also, please run the Dart code formatter on your code so it follows the default Dart style. That makes it more readable in general.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).