# How to create a six digit unique code in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a app which uses the refer and earn system in which i want to assign the 6 digit unique code to each user. Is there any method which can create the 6 digit unique alphanumeric code to each user.

Comment: If by chance you are using firebase and are open to a id longer than 6 digits you can use the logged in user's uid.

Answer (score 0):

You can either refer to this answer [How to generate random string in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61919395/how-to-generate-random-string-in-dart)

Or if you are open to a legitimate solution but compromise over its length of six, I highly recommend you to please use uuid
https://pub.dev/packages/uuid