# Flutter how to generate random strings

Tags: string, flutter, random

Hello does anyone know how I can only generate Strings with letters. Like :

"skdnjfsd" or "bdfvkjnd" ?

my current code :

```
String _randomString(int length) {
    var rand = new Random();
    var codeUnits = new List.generate(
        length,
            (index){
          return rand.nextInt(33)+89;
        }
    );

    return new String.fromCharCodes(codeUnits);
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate random string in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61919395/how-to-generate-random-string-in-dart)

Answer (score 3):

implement to your code this function

```
String getRandom(int length){
    const ch = 'AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz';
    Random r = Random();
    return String.fromCharCodes(Iterable.generate(
    length, (_) => ch.codeUnitAt(r.nextInt(ch.length))));
}
```

and after call it with length

the original answer : [How to generate random string in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61919395/how-to-generate-random-string-in-dart)

Answer (score 2):

As per the answer of @julemand101, you can do this:

````dart
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  print(getRandomString(5));  // 5GKjb
  print(getRandomString(10)); // LZrJOTBNGA
  print(getRandomString(15)); // PqokAO1BQBHyJVK
}

const _chars = 'AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz1234567890';
Random _rnd = Random();

String getRandomString(int length) => String.fromCharCodes(Iterable.generate(
    length, (_) => _chars.codeUnitAt(_rnd.nextInt(_chars.length))));```
````

Comment: Instead of coping the answer, you could have flagged the post as duplicate.