# How to randomise a-z letters in flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to do something like the

```
hello 1
hello 2
hello 3
```

but I want it to do this

```
fello
jello
aello
dello
```

Would I use dart:math to create a Random widget that produces a random integer and then somehow link it to the letters A-Z?

Thanks

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61919395/how-to-generate-random-string-in-dart

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to genarate a string array with all the alphabetic letters. Refer About `String.fromCharCode` for more information.

```
//This function will return a string list with alphabet
List<String> getAlphebat() {
  List<String> alphabets = [];
  for (int i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
    alphabets.add(String.fromCharCode(i));
  }
  return alphabets;
}
```

And with the help of Random class in `dart:math` you can generate a random number. and access the particular index and get a random letter.

```
void main() {
  
  //Random Generator
  var randomGen = Random();
  
  //Generated random letter
  print(getAlphebat()[randomGen.nextInt(26)]);
  
}
```

[String.fromCharCode](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/String/String.fromCharCode.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:math';

static getRandomString(length, [characterString]) {
  String _chars = characterString ?? 'AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz';
  Random _rnd = Random();
  return String.fromCharCodes(Iterable.generate(length, (_) => _chars.codeUnitAt(_rnd.nextInt(_chars.length))));
 }
```

Use below function to get random string, Here "character string" are optional to pass in function.

```
getRandomString(10, 'asABCCSSdsa');
```