# Flutter textfields in list not updating when list updates

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have this peculiar problem where I have a list of textfields in a dynamic list, as in a user can add/remove items, I have created a custom widget which houses two fields so basically the widget returns an map as a value, see below:

```
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: info.asMap().entries.map((el) => Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: _gap),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(_gap /2),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text('Index ${el.value}'),
                  ProductInfoInput(
                    value: el.value,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      print(value);
                      setState(() {
                        info[el.key] = value;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: _gap / 2),
                  OutlinedButton(
                    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(foregroundColor: Colors.red),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        info.removeAt(el.key);
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Text('Remove'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )).toList(),
          )
```

Don't worry about this line `Text('Index ${el.value}'),`, I just put it there to confirm my sanity, anyway the addition/deletion works, the problem is say if first item values were `{info: info1, val: value1}` and second item was `{info: info2, val: value2}`, upon deleting the first item it will delete fine and upon checking the the resulting object it will read `{info: info2, val: value2}`, but the textfields still display `{info: info1, val: value1}` values, where could I have gone wrong in this setup, any assistance would be highly appreciated

Comment: Could you let me know **ProductInfoInput** definition code in more detail?

Comment: does ProductInfoInput return a widget with some kind of ValueKey so that Column can tell if things have gotten removed or added?  See Emily's video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc

Comment: I was not using keys, now I have another problem but basically another step towards the right direction, thanks alot, this really helped @RandalSchwartz

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to resolve this and posting an answer to anyone who comes across this, the answer is **Keys** (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc). Watching the video gave me an idea of using `UniqueKey` but in my case I had form fields inside my custom widget `ProductInfoInput` so everytime there was an update it would refresh and the focus on the field would be lost, and that was on every key stroke, now I decided to use `ValueKey` with index but this one also had a flaw of the fact that if I delete the first item, when the index resets and all items move downwards the index, the other items displayed previous item values, e.g. item index 1 which is now item index 0 displayed item index 0 values which was the value of the deleted index 0 item, so my final solution was to include a unique param value that is constant and unique to each element item other than the index, e.g. {'key': {random value here}} (see this [How to generate random string in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61919395/how-to-generate-random-string-in-dart/61929967#61929967)), making the key look like `ValueKey(map['key'])`, this worked really well. Some blunders become obvious after you commit them, its part of the learning process.

**TLDR;**

Use a key in widgets list specifically a `ValueKey` with a unique value to distinguish the items, avoid using index as key, you can generate like a random value that will be unique and add it to valuekey e.g. `ValueKey(randomValue)`